# sort file of multiple numbers with text behind them

Tags: python, file, sorting

good evening everyone, I would like to help specifically with the sort

the data is always on a different line and the text is behind the numbers

```
20:10:20 text
2:10:20 text
1:10:20 text
22:10:1 text
21:10:19 text
20:10:1 text
```

and they need to arrange it by numbers

so if the input is the example above, I expect the output to sort all numbers [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAFhZ.png)[2]

I am looking for this

```
1:10:20 text
2:10:20 text
20:10:1 text
20:10:20 text
21:10:19 text
22:10:1 text


with open ("1.txt") as f:
         unsolved = (f.read (). split ())
         sor = sorted(unsolved)
for unsolved_elem in sor:
```

the problem is that it gives the result in the wrong order

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAFhZ.png)

Can someone help me with this? thanks to all for your help

Comment: you will have to read all lines and convert strings with numbers (ie. `"20"`) to integers (`20`) - and later you can sort it.

Comment: @furas     `set_data = set(set_data_str.split('\n'))`


`sorted_set_data = sorted(set_data)`


`print('\n'.join(sorted_set_data))`   I have this but I don't know how to apply it to a file

Comment: updated now add picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you compare strings and it compars char by char using char's code - so it comapars strings `"20"` and `"2:"`, not integer values `20` and `2` - and char `"0"` is before char `":"` because `"0"` has code `48` and `":"` has code `58`.

You have to first split string `"1:10:20 text"` to tuple/list of strings `("1", "10", "20", "text")` and later convert numbers to integers `(1, 10, 20, "text")` - and it will sort it correctly.

I use `io` to create file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and test it - but you should use `open()`

```
data = '''20:10:20 text
2:10:20 text
1:10:20 text
22:10:1 text
21:10:19 text
20:10:1 text'''

import io

# --- create tuples ---

rows = []

#with open('11000.txt', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as r:
with io.StringIO(data) as r:    
    for line in r:
        line = line.strip()  # remove `\n` at the end
        numbers, text = line.split(' ')  # split 
        numbers = numbers.split(':')     # split numbers

        rows.append( [int(numbers[0]),int(numbers[1]),int(numbers[2]), line] )

# --- sorting ---

for row in sorted(rows):
   print(row[-1])
```

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) problem is text

Comment: `numbers, text = line.split(' ',1)` thanx

Comment: tested on a larger number of data, unfortunately it does not work, it has the same problem as my script

and that there are results

`67,9,57`
`7,1,5`
which is a bad position im add for you script picture look

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAFhZ.png

Comment: `[int(numbers[0]),int(numbers[1]),(numbers[2]), line]` this working `[int(numbers[0]),int(numbers[1]),int(numbers[2]), line]` this no RIP `

Comment: mi bad 1 rows have bad input tab